# How does garbage collector identify roots

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, gc-roots

The first phase of a mark-sweep garbage collector is to mark(find) all the live objects on the heap. To do this, there must be a starting point or root, from where all the marking begins. How does GC identify such roots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the technique called root set enumeratios all roots will be identified. Here is sentence from Mark-sweep patent document.

**In the first phase, all direct references to objects from currently running programs may be identified. These references are called roots, or together a root set, and a process of identifying all such references may be called root set enumeration**

Here is link for patent document. [Mark sweep patent link](http://www.patents.com/us-7197521.html)

Eventhough it was by .NET guy, I feel [Basics of mark sweep](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/01/30/back-to-basics-mark-and-sweep-garbage-collection.aspx) link will give you good understanding on how it works.

Answer (score 3):

"A distinguished set of objects are assumed to be reachable: these are known as the roots. Typically, these include **all the objects referenced from anywhere in the call stack (that is, all local variables and parameters in the functions currently being invoked), and any global variables.**

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Reachability_of_an_object)