# JVM GC and unused references

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Let's say there are following four objects in a Java program:

- main
- a
- b
- c

The dependencies are as follows:

**main** ==> **a** ==> **b** ==> **c**

In other words, **main** uses **a**, **a** uses **b**, **b** uses **c**.

Now, value of object **a** changes from reference to **b** to **null**. What it means is that there are no active references to **b**, making it available for garbage collection:

**main** ==> **a** =/=> **b** ==> **c**

What could happen now:

A) In laymans terms, **b** can be garbage collected at any time. My **assumption** is that **c** will become elligible for gargabe collection only after **b** is garbage collected.

B) However, I imagine this could be a case that JVM could somehow distinguish between references to **c** from GC-eligible and non-GC-eligible objects, and therefore mark **c** as eligible at the same time as **b**.

Is the behaviour determined by Java Language Specification, or any JVM-related specification? Or is it left for the JVM implementation to decide?

Comment: Some related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451346/how-garbage-collector-works-under-the-hood-to-collect-dead-object, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812635/how-does-garbage-collector-identify-roots?rq=1, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587868/java-how-can-garbage-collector-quickly-know-which-objects-do-not-have-referenc?rq=1

Comment: All that a garbage collector cares for, is that `main` and `a` are still reachable. Everything else is garbage. Despite its misleading name, a garbage collector never looks at the garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this link, I believe option B is correct:
https://www.dynatrace.com/resources/ebooks/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works/
Once **b** and **c** are no longer reachable from GC roots, they are both collectible at the same time.